# Alternatives for Memcached in a shared hosting

Tags: security, caching, memcached, shared-hosting

I read this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139629/is-it-safe-to-use-memcached-in-a-shared-hosting-environment) and [grochmal](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/112042/grochmal) said that

> Therefore, using memcached as any networked solution notably in a hosting environment is simply unwise.

So, what method do I need to do, to make my website faster? In my case, my I/O always hits it's limit due to use of database query for every requests. Memcached is the only way I think that can solve my problem, but they said it's not wise to use it in a hosting environment (shared). I am in a shared hosting environment too, so, what I need to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in [symcbeans answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/139655/98538) to the same question:

> Encrypting all the data you store in memcache would solve the disclosure problem (but creates a key management problem). It doesn't prevent damage to the data.

Solve the key management problem in the same way you solve it for your primary data source. If that solution is good enough for the primary data source, it is good enough for the cache.

Regarding damage to data, a simple server crach would be enough to wipe out your data. If you are concerned about damage, you should not rely on Memcached to begin with.

Comment: In key management problem is that where the key corrupts or something? And to the damage data, what is the server crach? and my database will be wiped out?

Comment: The key management problem is where to store the encryption key. Store it where you store the password to your primary data source. A server crash is your server shutting down and restarting for some reason. If that happends, everything stored in Memcached will be gone. But since it is only a cache (or?) that should not be a huge problem.

Comment: so, I use the key for encryption, then I always fetch it up to database or store it to  cached too?

Comment: @googol8080 I'm not sure I understand your question. You use the key to encrypt everything going into the cache, and decrypt everything comming out of it. You do not store the key in the cache - that would make the encryption pointless.

Comment: Then every time I check the cache I go to db search the key and then decrypt it?